Understanding safety concerns with RGB modding hot-chassis TV
I'm in the US. I'd like clarifications on the safety of RGB modding an old, hot-chassis TV. I know it's not economically viable but I'd like to learn. While researching how to do this safely I realized I'm racking up a lot of assumptions I'm sure are at least incorrect if not dangerous. What about the following is incorrect or better stated another way?
The outer shell of a RCA input jack is bonded to the chassis of a TV. The chassis in a cold-chassis TV is bonded to ground. The chassis in a hot-chassis TV is bonded to either neutral or live so inputs must be isolated. Isolating inputs makes them "floating". A floating input's ground is set by the game console. The RF input can be isolated with a capacitor.
Assuming I'm plugging a TV directly into mains instead of into an IST, then the potential of a hot-chassis TV will depend on which direction the plug was physically inserted. The chassis will either be neutral or live. If I measure the TV plug to find the chassis and measure the wall outlet to verify neutral, I can plug them together and the chassis will be neutral. With a neutral chassis I can safely connect a game console to the jungle IC. This will work but is dumb because the TV could only ever be safely used in verified outlets.
A sneaky followup: How can I isolate RGB input with capacitors like is done with RF input to avoid needing an IST?

"Neutral" isn't necessarly at ground potential. What you're suggesting is still unsafe even if plugged in the "correct" way around. The reason for this is resistive voltage drop across the wires leading to the outlet and TV: When a large load is plugged in on the same circuit, the current draw will cause the voltage on the neutral wire to increase far beyond 0V. For example, if you have a 10A load on a circuit with 1 Ohm of resistance in the neutral (not unheard of), you now have 10V AC on the neutral, and therefore on the chassis of the TV and the attached RCA jacks. If you then connect this to another (grounded) device, you short this voltage to ground, which is still at the proper 0V because it's a separate wire. An excessive current will flow, damaging the attached device and potentially setting the wire on fire. (10A at 10V is 100W for this little example!)
Also, if the neutral wire ever fails open, the TV and everything attached to it is instantly live.
Don't do this.
You could use ferrite signal transformers for isolation, although you'd probably have to wind them yourself.

I have never heard of isolating video signals with transformers. Most likely there is a good reason why it's not done, or at least very rare, like requiring basically flat bandwidth ranging from at least from 10Hz to about 4.2 MHz, preferably larger. However, I've seen TV schematics that use optoisolators for this task.

Very helpful! So the tiny resistance of the wires in my wall is enough to cause a not insignificant voltage on neutral that would be shorted directly to ground through my poor game console? Wow. For my complete understanding, what would happen if the game console was not grounded?

@Justme isolating video signals with transformers is (was) an established practice for an rf modulated signals.

@fraxinus Exactly and it still is - but this question is not about RF modulated video, but adding an RGB input, which is baseband video. Which sort of reminds me, adding the RGB pins is not enough. The sync signals are also needed.

@Justme Signal transformers can be surprisingly awesome - I've built some with ungapped RM8 cores recently to replace very expensive differential amps on a signal processing board. They had a flat frequency response from a few hundred Hertz to 5+ MHz. Given that the DC offset of the RGB signal levels is zeroed out on every scanline (via the front porch after the sync pulse), it should be sufficient if the transformers pass something like 1kHz to 5MHz. 50 turns (bifilar) on a RM12 N30 core might work well.

@JonathanS. now you fix the phase distortion and it could work

There are TVs that use optoisolators for providing isolated inputs to a hot chassis design.
RGB video uses 60 Hz field rate so you need to pass frequencies much less than 60 Hz to prevent 'drooping' of the AC coupled video signal, so the AC coupling capacitors will have to pass the 60 Hz of the mains as well, so it can't be isolated with capacitors.
You also need to feed in sync signal too, so be prepared to either use sync-on-green, or a separate composite sync might be needed. Which is why YUV input might make even more sense than RGB.

I might try optoisolators as a project once I'm more knowledgeable but for now I'm probably just going to throw $$ at the problem and buy an IST. What about capacitors? Do they only work for RF (I'm thinking maybe carrier waves behave like AC and sneak past)?

@lwiseman I do not recommend spending money on IST just yet - it's not a long-term solution and leakage currents through stray capacitances can be problematic (ever felt a "sting" when touching ungrounded devices or damaged them when connecting two together?) Capacitors work for RF only because high frequencies work over small capacitors while 60Hz mains gets through them poorly. RGB video needs preferably DC coupling or frequencies below 60 Hz anyway to pass well, so RGB can't be isolated with capacitors as it would be deadly.

I apologize for bumping an old post but I've been trying to learn about an optoisolation solution like you proposed and I had a few newbie questions about your posts. The biggest is how I power the optoisolator's led? If I steal power from the TV wouldn't I be defeating the isolation? Also, what's the highest frequency I would need to pass for quality baseband video? Sorry again for bumping I've just been fascinated after finally grasping what you meant about the capacitors (DC is just AC with a frequency of 0, the capacitors "pass" >x Hz).

@lwiseman Yes you can't use power from the non-isolated side to power something on the isolated side - you would firs have to make a new isolated power supply, maybe from mains, maybe from the non-isolated side. Bandwidth could be around 7 MHz - digital 720 pixel wide formats use 13.5 MHz pixel clock for interlaced video.

So cool, you've kindled a legit passion in this field for me, thanks! Kind of a long shot, but now that you have an understanding of my knowledge level, any recommendations on where I can learn more? My googlefu seemingly leads me to "ohm's law for 5 year olds" or "inductance matching for quantum computing phd grads" ;)

@lwiseman I don't think there is a ready made answer for "how to add an adequate quality isolated RGB input safely into a dangerous hot chassis TV". That's too much in one book/website.

Hahaha, fair enough. Thank you so much for the help. It's truly appreciated. Edit: I promise I'll try to be honest with myself about safety vs. my understanding.
